# PHP fgets() warning

Tags: php, fopen, fgets

I have following code:

```
$fh=fopen($api,"r");
$theData = fgets($fh);
echo $theData;
```

This throws the error as :

```
Warning: fopen(http://xxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.com:8080) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Connection refused in /home/xxxx/public_html/xxxx/index.php on line 18

Warning: fgets(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/xxxx/public_html/xxxx/index.php on line 19
```

What is the solution for this?

Comment: You could try removing the `@` on your `fopen`, and see if it's returning an error - are you sure that `$api` is defined and pointing where you expect?

Comment: ok.. you're right, its throwing the error.. let me update the post

Comment: Try getting the file using CURL instead of fopen.

Comment: the culprit is the remote host you are trying to open. and not the script itself. Check that the remote resource is available and that you have typed the correct url to it.

Comment: how to use curl? Can you post the code in answer pls?

Comment: @Prakash - the PHP site has a lot of useful information: http://us.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file did not open as you intended. Check the value of $api and be sure the file name is in the current working directory, or the entire path to the file.

Since it is a remote system on :8080, be sure the port is open to the public. This is typically a value reserved for localhost (ie: the webserver is only a webserver to that computer, no one else's) and wouldn't be accessible to you. If the url you are opening is the same computer you are using, navigate to the file using local folders instead.

Comment: its the the file infact, its the external website url -- using as api